# Retrieve data from multiple tables - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, join

I am doing a search interface from multiple tables using UNION. The class where in the search words are filtered, are in a SimpleCursorAdapter form, my problem is when I click the searched word for its information the only thing I see is a white blank page.

Here is my code for retrieving the 'for more information' words. And I think the problem is in the WHERE condition. Please help me. Thanks.

```
commandId = getIntent().getIntExtra("COMMAND_ID", 0);
SQLiteDatabase db = (new DBHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
final String commandIdString = String.valueOf(commandId);
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc, syntax AS syntax, option AS option FROM comm_acc WHERE _id = ? " +
        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc, syntax AS syntax, option AS option FROM comm_filems WHERE _id = ? " +
        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc, syntax AS syntax, option AS option FROM comm_psu WHERE _id = ? " +
        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc, syntax AS syntax, option AS option FROM comm_shells WHERE _id = ? " +
        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id, name AS name, desc AS desc, syntax AS syntax, option AS option FROM comm_sic WHERE _id = ? " +
        "UNION SELECT _id AS _id,name AS name, desc AS desc, syntax AS syntax, option AS option FROM comm_stp WHERE _id = ?", 
        new String[]{commandIdString, commandIdString, commandIdString, commandIdString, commandIdString, commandIdString});


if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
{
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        commandName = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.commandName);
        commandName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

        commandDesc = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.commandDesc);
        commandDesc.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("desc")));

        commandSyntax = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.commandSyntax);
        commandSyntax.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syntax")));

        commandOption = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.commandOption);
        commandOption.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option")));

}

}
```

Comment: Have you used the resulting SQL query against the DB?

Comment: It wont solve your problem, but: ""+commandId is messy. Why not use: String.valueOf(commandId), instead?

Comment: I've already edited the codes, please see again. It's still the same, white blank page.

Answer (score 1):

For every parameter you use in your raw query, you have to set the value to replace, so

```
new String[]{""+commandId}
```

only fits for the first parameter in the list. Replace it with

```
final String commandIdString = String.valueOf(commandId);
new String[]{commandIdString, commandIdString, commandIdString, commandIdString, commandIdString, commandIdString}
```

Comment: Still the same, only white page. Please see again, I have edited the codes.

Comment: What about the "Have you used the resulting SQL query against the DB?"-part to rule out SQL syntax-related problems?

Comment: Yes, I've tried executing it without the WHERE condition and it works fine. Is there something wrong in my WHERE Condition?

Comment: It is *your* job to find out - debug the code, find the complete SQL query, execute it, check the result and check LogCat whether any exceptions are occurring.